# The Schwartz genus of a fibration

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, algebraic-combinatorics, translation-request

I'm working on the topological complexity of a path connected space, which is a particular case of the sectional category (or the Schwartz genus), but all the articles refer to an other article named "the Schwartz genus of a fiber space" published by A.S.Schwarz. [enter link description here](http://m.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=mmo&paperid=120&option_lang=eng) The problem is that it is written by Russian language. I can't find it in English. Can someone help me?